# Affine Varieties are locally complete intersections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As the title indicates, my question has to do with the "local structure" of an affine variety. So, is it true that for a given affine variety i.e. a zero locus of the form $X=V(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{n}) \subset \mathbb{k}^{n}$ where $\mathbb{k}$ an arbitrary field, is locally a complete intersection?

Also, by complete intersection I do mean strict-complete intersection (in Hartshorne's sense). What does it change if instead of strict we put set-theoritic complete intersection? And instead of affine, "projrctive"?

Comment: thank you for the reply Hoot! though, I could edit my question by specifying to restrict into non-singular varieties, but would prefer something more general. However I still don't get the answer in that case as well! So if you can help me that would be helpful!

Comment: You mean the localization or the quotient? Because I think Hartshorne is referering to localizations at primes of regular rings are regular rings as well, or so?

Comment: Yes, you are right! thank you! that's a step forward!

Answer (score 4):

Wow! Hoot, I did see the question, but how did you think I could have something to say?

As pointed out, any smooth (or regular) variety is a local complete intersection. The standard example of a non-local complete intersection would be the image if the map $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^3$, $t\mapsto (t^3, t^4, t^5)$. If you are thinking locally, I do not know what you mean by affine or projective in the last part of your question.

I do not know a variety which is not a local complete intersection set-theoretically. One of the standard examples of a non-irreducible one is due to Hartshorne, the two planes in 4-space meeting only at the origin (cone over two skew lines in projective 3-space).

Comment: I've been reading papers on Kontsevich spaces all day and made a guess — sorry for calling you out! It's amazing what isn't known.